# jQuery call ajax new div dynamic ID's

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have in the layout file
<

```
script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    // Datepicker
    $('#passExp1').datepicker({
        inline: true
   });
});
</script>
```

In a view

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function addInput(divName) {
  ... code to add the new div with form fields...

   newCalendar="passExp"+(counter+1);

   newFunction(newCalendar);

}

</script>
```

how can I create a newFunction to call the newCalendar (which is the new form id) to add the datePicker to it?

I want to make it use the DatePicker for the **new passExp2,passExp3,passExp4,passExp5,...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the value of the `newCalendar` parameter is the id of the new div, you could do this in your function:

```
$('#' + newCalendar).datePicker();
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple but I just don't use jQuery a lot. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use a better JS organization (well mine isn't so good, too) but you should do something like this in a JS file:

**jscode.js**

```
newCalendar(selector){
    $(selector).datepicker({
        inline: true
   });
});

function addInput(divName) {
  ... code to add the new div with form fields...
   selector="passExp"+(counter+1);
   newCalendar(selector);
}
```

Then include your js file in the view: `<script src="jscode.js"></script>`

And it should work, when working with jQuery its easier to create the CSS selector and put them in the $() object, in this example i don't see necessary to create a function to the calendar, you can put it inside the **addInput** function

Comment: This is demo code to get the fix for the problem I am running into this is not the real code but as close as I can get to it to get an answer.